# Best approach to go through tv series, annote key scenes?

Tags: video

There's this great TV series that I am a fan of. I would like to go through each episode, available on DVD, and make note of interesting scenes, i.e. funnt stuff, reoccurring events, etc. Is there a good way to go about this? I know that shows such as The Daily show do something like this in order to find relevant clips for their show.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Mac, iPhone or iPad I would suggest [Bento](http://www.filemaker.com/products/bento/). It's a program based on FileMaker that allows you to organize all sorts of projects and data.  You could try this [Film Library](http://solutions.filemaker.com/database-templates/detail.jsp?serial=2550209) template from their template exchange or search for a different template.  Or maybe just download the program and start entering data.